# Is it legitimate for rel prev / next links to indicate a circular sequence of pages?

Tags: links, meta-tags, pagination, accessibility, link-prefetching

Before anything else, ***yes***, Google no longer takes note of `rel prev / next` and has not done so (officially) for nearly a year. Google officially deprecated `rel prev / next` as a crawl / indexing factor on **March 21st, 2019**:

- https://www.ayima.com/blog/relprev-next-officially-deprecated-where-do-we-go-next.html

Unofficially, Google stopped taking note of `rel prev / next` several years before that.

But, as with any web document meta information, just because Google isn't using `rel prev / next`, doesn't mean it no longer represents useful library information.

In fact, Google itself even highlights this:

- https://searchengineland.com/google-apologizes-for-relnext-prev-mixup-314494

`rel prev / next` may, not least:

- assist accessibility
- represent a `resource pre-fetching` hint to browsers.

---

So, here I am, one year after the official announcement still using `rel prev / next` perfectly happily to create a chain of product pages which each show and discuss one of a set of associated products.

To date, I have use `rel prev / next` to indicate a straight line of product pages from first product page to last product page:

*Product 1 Page ==> Product 2 Page ==> Product 3 Page*

That's it.

Consequently:

- **Product 1 Page** doesn't have a `<link rel="prev">`; and
- **Product 3 Page** doesn't have a `<link rel="next">`

But would there be anything nonsensical and / or illegitimate about giving **Product 3 Page** a `<link rel="next">` which points to **Product 1 Page** and vice versa?

***e.g.*** *Product 3 ==> Product 1 ==> Product 2 ==> Product 3 ==> Product 1*

I'd very much like to implement this, but I want to check first that creating a circular sequence of pages isn't, in principle, an abuse of pagination, somehow.

Comment: I've been away doing another piece of work, but I'm back to this again. Does anyone know of an authoritative source which might confirm (or not) that an endless loop of `C => A => B => C => A => B` etc. is a legitimate series for `rel prev / next` links?

Comment: I'm not sure that `rel prev / next` is appropriate to use between product pages at all.   There isn't a particular order in which product pages have to be viewed.   Prev and next are for things like pagination that have a definite order.

Comment: Thanks, @StephenOstermiller - in this case there is a particular order in which the product pages _ought_ to be viewed, though, you're right, it's not obligatory to view them in that order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three and a half months later I have come back to this with an entirely satisfactory solution.

I was unaware of this when I posted the question above in March 2020, but way back in 2011, the **W3C** included this section in its then-working-draft of **HTML5**:

> ***Sequential link types***
>
> *Some documents form part of a sequence of documents. A sequence of documents is one where each document can have a previous sibling and a
> next sibling. A document with no previous sibling is the start of its
> sequence, a document with no next sibling is the end of its sequence.*
>
> **Source:** https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/links.html#sequential-link-types

It then goes on to reference not only:

- `<link rel="prev">`
- `<link rel="next">`

but *also*:

- `<link rel="first">`
- `<link rel="last">`

---

This discovery of `<link rel="first">` and `<link rel="last">` proved to be key.

It means that whereas before I could only think of creating an infinite loop which operates like this:

*Product 3 ==> Product 1 ==> Product 2 ==> Product 3 ==> Product 1 ==> Product 2 ==> Product 3 ==> Product 1 ==> Product 2 ==> Product 3 ==> Product 1 ==> Product 2 ==> Product 3 ==> Product 1 ==> Product 2 ==> Product 3 ==> Product 1 ==> Product 2 ==> Product 3 ==> Product 1 ==> Product 2 ==> Product 3 ==> Product 1 ==> Product 2 ==> Product 3 ==> Product 1 ==> Product 2 ==> Product 3 ==> Product 1*

in which:

- *Product 3* has a `<link rel="next">` pointing to *Product 1*
- *Product 1* has a `<link rel="prev">` pointing to *Product 3*

I can now, instead, (and much more straightforwardly) use:

*Product 1 ==> Product 2 ==> Product 3*

in which:

- *Product 1* has no `<link rel="prev">`
- *Product 3* has no `<link rel="next">`
- *all product pages* have a `<link rel="first">` pointing to *Product 1*
- *all product pages* have a `<link rel="last">` pointing to *Product 3*

---

**N.B.** In 2020, the *contemporary* HTML spec (as opposed to the [HTML5 2011 Working Draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/links.html#sequential-link-types)) makes no reference to `<link rel="first">` and `<link rel="last">` but the rest of the section on ***Sequential link types*** remains largely unchanged.

**See:** *https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#sequential-link-types*

No matter. If there remains an official recognition that documents may form a sequence and that there is utility in a sequential document being able to describe its relationships to certain other documents in that sequence, it seems perfectly reasonable (to me, at this point) that any sequential document ought to have the option to point to the first and last documents in the sequence.

Perhaps, one day, the **WHAT-WG** will reintroduce `<link rel="first">` and `<link rel="last">` to the official HTML spec (?)